# Insufficient Privileges On Custom Object Deletion

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, scratch-org, package

> I am observing a weird behaviour on scratch org, When I tried to delete the custom object it throw an "Insufficient Privileges" error, but this is happening when only financial service cloud package installed to your scratch org.

[image]

Steps to reproduce.

```
Step 1: Create a new scratch org.

Step 2: Now you're able to create custom object in salesforce and you can delete it also successfully 

Step 3: install financial cloud service package  
`sfdx force:package:install --wait 100 --publishwait 100  --package 04t1E000000jb9R   --noprompt `

Step 4: Now your able create custom object in salesforce but not able to delete it , You get above error.
```

One more interesting fact is, i have created new trail org form  [Financial Services Cloud Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/fsc_setup/fsc_setup_unit_1) but i didn't observed this behaviour in that org.

Updated:

`project-scratch-def.json` file

```
{
  "orgName": "Company Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
    "Sites",
    "Communities",
    "FinancialServicesUser:5",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "PersonAccounts"
  ],
  "hasSampleData": true,
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "experienceBundleSettings": {
      "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: what's in your `project-scratch-def.json`?

Comment: @kris-goncalves Updated project-scratch-def.json

Comment: Happening for me too, in a sandbox with source tracking turned on.  Was able to delete the object directly in production with no issue

Comment: @MoDiggity Thanks... Its an weird thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this article which solved the problem for me: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8yovSAB

After enabling language translation, deleting custom objects started working for me.

Go salesforce!

Comment: This is hilarious!

Comment: Three years later, today, I faced the same issue and it worked for me too! :) Its still hilarious!